# Install certbot ubuntu 21.10 unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, certbot

I am trying to install certbot on ubuntu server 21.10 with the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04.

But when I run the following command:

```
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

I get the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 certbot : Depends: python3-certbot (= 1.12.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-zope.component : Depends: python3-zope.hookable but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried the command:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

But this does not seem to fix my issue.

I am not sure why I am getting this error message. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install certbot as snap package instead. I've never had problems with it.

```
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core

sudo snap install --classic certbot

sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

Then you could do something like this if you are running apache.

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're running an [unsupported release of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle). That means they've removed the packages from repositories, and no further updates will be made.

Do ***not*** run unsupported Ubuntu releases unless you know how to do this in a sane manner (e.g. use archive.ubuntu.com).

Furthermore, you probably want the LTS release on a server.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will look into updating to an LTS release.